# Zsh parameter expansion on output of command s flag doesn't work

Tags: shell, zsh, parameter-expansion

In zsh, if I run:

```
a=$(echo "foo, bar")
echo ${a[(ws:, :)1]}
```

I get `foo` as you would expect (`w` causes the index to refer to words `s:, :` makes `,` be the word separator).

However, if I try to combine these:

```
echo ${$(echo "foo, bar")[(ws:, :)1]}
```

I get `foo,`. For some reason the `w` flag is working correctly, but the `s:, :` flag is completely ignored.

What am I doing wrong here?

**More info:** This is just a problem with $() inside ${}. If I nest ${} inside ${} there is no such problem.

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 0):

Field splitting is done before the index operation kicks in, so the behaviour you see is what I would expect. You can get the expected result by

```
echo ${"$(echo "foo, bar")"[(ws:, :)1]}
```

One note aside: My first attempt was to rewrite your expression using the *?{==...}* form of parameter substitution, which is supposed to inhibit field splitting, i.e.

```
echo ${${==$(echo "foo, bar")}[(ws:, :)1]}
```

and this did **not** work. I have no idea why...

Comment: `${==` only unsets the sh_word_split option for the expansion. In effect, that is only asserting a default and is unlikely to have much effect.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by "field splitting" and "index operation", and why your solution works? It seems like quoting "$(echo " and ")" would just give a syntax error.

Comment: Could it be that you are using an older Zsh version? You can leave out the inner quotes or replace them by single quotes. See [this screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/47xhi0zwz/).

Comment: oh. I see what's happening with tthe quoting now. I still don't understand what is meant by "field splitting"